# On what topologies do homeomorphisms with cyclic elements, cycle all elements?

Tags: general-topology, p-adic-number-theory, permutation-cycles

Let $T$ be a homeomorphism from a topological space to itself with a set of cyclic points, for example on the 2-adic units $\Bbb Z_2^\times$ that $T$ cycles $(-1,1,\frac13,-\frac13)$.

In general, and in this specific case, must it cycle other points in the space?

It seems clear that in general it must not because e.g. in the discrete topology I think one could cycle the given points and leave all the others fixed and have a homeomorphism.  But as one makes the topology coarser, there is less freedom. Is there some threshold where this forces other points to cycle?

I'm aware of one weaker statement, which is Sharkovski's theorem, which in the above case on $\Bbb R$ instead of $\Bbb Z_2^\times$ would guarantee cyclic points of orders $2$ as well as fixed points. Obviously cases can be manufactured, but are there broad categories of topologies that require the whole space cycles together?

Comment: Certainly, it doesn't need to cycle all other points. But other than that, I'm not sure if there has to be at least one more cycle.

Comment: For example, in the complex plane, $z\mapsto e^{2\pi |z|i}z$ has cycles exactly for $|z|$ rational.

Comment: Your counterexample works both in the finest (discrete) and the coarsest (trivial) topology. There might be something interesting happening in between, but in your seeting one cannot say there would be "less freedom" either by going to finer or coarser topologies. (The issue is that you endow domain and codomain with the same topology. If you go in one direction on one, you can make statements, but in a way they work in opposite directions. I.e. if you make the domain finer you might get something, but making the codomain finer might lose that again.)

Comment: Thanks @TorstenSchoeneberg that's illuminating that coarseness/fineness act both ways in increasing and restricting freedom, depending whether it's the domain or codomain.